# Full text search using Postgresql (and Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, full-text-search

In my app there are customers, which have their individual fields stored in a 'keywords' column (first_name, last_name and email).

I want to perform a full text search on keywords column using GIN index. This is my migration:

```
class AddKeywordIndexToCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute %{
        CREATE INDEX
            customers_keywords_index ON customers
        USING
            gin(to_tsvector('english', keywords));
    }
  end

  def down
    remove_index :customers, name: 'customers_keywords_index'
  end
end
```

This is my customer class:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :set_keywords

    scope :search, -> (search) {where('keywords LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase}%")}

    scope :ft_search, -> (search) {where("(to_tsvector('english', keywords) @@ to_tsquery(?))", search)}

    protected

    def set_keywords
        self.keywords = [first_name, last_name, email].map(&:downcase).join(' ')
    end
end
```

(both scopes are there for comparison reasons)

My controller looks fairly simple:

```
def index
  @customers = Customer.ft_search(@keywords)
end
```

However it does not return anything. Not even an error, just zero rows.

In my dbconsole:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE to_tsvector('english', 'keywords') @@ to_tsquery('bob');
 id | first_name | last_name | email | username | created_at | updated_at | keywords 
----+------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+----------
(0 rows)
```

'bob' should return at least something since I've got 350.000 random seed data and my first scope returns 214 rows (or 1750?):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(keywords) like 'bob%' ORDER BY keywords ASC;
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=12282.26..12286.64 rows=1750 width=123) (actual time=319.566..319.582 rows=214 loops=1)
   Sort Key: keywords
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 77kB
   ->  Seq Scan on customers  (cost=0.00..12188.00 rows=1750 width=123) (actual time=1.653..317.625 rows=214 loops=1)
         Filter: (lower(keywords) ~~ 'bob%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 349786
 Planning time: 0.415 ms
 Execution time: 319.642 ms
```

I may have an error in my ruby code, but why does even the plain SQL query return 0 rows?

Comment: Can you execute this query: `select ts_debug('english', keywords) from customers where lower(keywords) like 'bob%' limit 3`

Comment: This is my output:
`select ts_debug('english', keywords) from customers where lower(keywords) like 'bob%' limit 3;
                                 ts_debug                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",bobbie,{english_stem},english_stem,{bobbi})
 (blank,"Space symbols"," ",{},,)
 (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",schoen,{english_stem},english_stem,{schoen})
(3 rows)`

Comment: In the first select query you have 'keywords' in quotes. Try removing the quotes.